# Can I Update the string message of a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-widget

I set up a progressdialog in an Android AsyncTak and it works.

My question is it possible to update in the onProgressUpdate method of the AsyncTask the string that the ProgressDialog displays. I would like to update the string with a publishProgress call to show progress of the task.

I can update the string if instead of the progressDialog I have my own textview. The progressDialog looks better and has the spinning wheel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can.  Simply call `myProgressDialog.setMessage("My New Message");` in `onProgressUpdate` method

Answer (score 0):

If you'll change message more then once:

```
@Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... values) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
            progress.setMessage(values[0]);
                        }
            });
        }
```