# Android: get/retrieve progressDialog message

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve the message text of a progressDialog dynamically when it is showing and modify the text inside
what I'm trying to do exactrly is something like this :

```
if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){ //pDialog is a ProgressDialog

    String message=pDialog.getMessage(); // method do not exist
    message=message+"Some text"
   pDialog.setMessage(message);

}
```

I searched and the only solution I found was to implement a custom content. I think there should be a simple way to do it.
As explained I'm trying to get the current message first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Update the string message of a ProgressDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009288/can-i-update-the-string-message-of-a-progressdialog)

Comment: completely different question I'm trying first to get the current message

Comment: There's no way to do that. One option is to save the message in a variable, update the variable with the new one and set it again. The variable will always have the most recent message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution so I'm sharing it thanks.

```
if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        TextView tv = (TextView) pDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        if(tv!=null){
            String pdtext=tv.getText().toString();
            pdtext=pdtext+"\n"+"Some text";

            pDialog.setMessage(pdtext);
        }

}
```